# Inverse powers of Bessel process not a martingale

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I am trying to show that $X_t^{1-2a}$ is not a martingale, where the solution $X_t$ to
$$dX_t = \frac{a}{X_t} \ dt + \ dB_t, \ \ X_0=1$$
for $a>1/2$. I am able to do this directly for $a = (d-1)/2$, because then $X_t$ is the norm of the standard $d-$dimensional Brownian motion starting on the sphere of radius $1$. I also have the following facts: $X_t \to \infty$ almost surely as $t \to \infty$, as well as 
$$\mathbb{P}(X_t \text{ hits } R \text{ before } \epsilon) = \frac{1- \epsilon^{1-2a}}{R^{1-2a} - \epsilon^{1-2a}}.$$
Here $\epsilon < 1<R$. If $X_t$ had started at $x$ we would replace $1$ there with $x^{1-2a}$. But I am not sure how to use these facts to show that $M_t\equiv X_t^{1-2a}$ is not a martingale. I can't seem to justify the limit swap to show $\mathbb{E}[M_t] \to 0$. In particular there doesn't seem to be anything I can dominate with. If there were some uniform integrability I could use Egorov and be done, but I just don't know enough about the Bessel process to know if this is true. Does anyone have any hints?

Comment: Have you tried to apply Ito's formula to find the SDE of $X_t^{1-2a}$? If the $dt$ terms in the resulting SDE does not vanish, then it is not a martingale? (Maybe it is not rigorous enough?)

Comment: @BGM It does vanish but this only shows that $X_t^{1-2a}$ is a **local** martingale.

Comment: It seems that one possibility is to apply Girsanov's theorem, see [Theorem 2.11 in this paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00022704/document)